# Returning singular row/value from joined table date based on closest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Production Table and a Standing Data table. The relationship of Production to Standing Data is actually Many-To-Many which is different to how this relationship is usually represented (Many-to-One).

The standing data table holds a list of tasks and the score each task is worth. Tasks can appear multiple times with different "ValidFrom" dates for changing the score at different points in time. What I am trying to do is query the Production Table so that the TaskID is looked up in the table and uses the date it was logged to check what score it should return.

Here's an example of how I want the data to look:

**Production Table:**

```
+----------+------------+-------+-----------+--------+-------+
| RecordID |    Date    | EmpID | Reference | TaskID | Score |
+----------+------------+-------+-----------+--------+-------+
|        1 | 27/02/2020 |     1 |       123 |      1 |   1.5 |
|        2 | 27/02/2020 |     1 |       123 |      1 |   1.5 |
|        3 | 30/02/2020 |     1 |       123 |      1 |     2 |
|        4 | 31/02/2020 |     1 |       123 |      1 |     2 |
+----------+------------+-------+-----------+--------+-------+
```

**Standing Data**

```
+----------+--------+----------------+-------+
| RecordID | TaskID | DateActiveFrom | Score |
+----------+--------+----------------+-------+
|        1 |      1 | 01/02/2020     |   1.5 |
|        2 |      1 | 28/02/2020     |     2 |
+----------+--------+----------------+-------+
```

I have tried the below code but unfortunately due to multiple records meeting the criteria, the production data duplicates with two different scores per record:

```sql
SELECT p.[RecordID],
       p.[Date],
       p.[EmpID],
       p.[Reference],
       p.[TaskID],
       s.[Score]
  FROM ProductionTable as p
  LEFT JOIN StandingDataTable as s
       ON s.[TaskID] = p.[TaskID]
      AND s.[DateActiveFrom] <= p.[Date];
```

What is the correct way to return the correct and singular/scalar Score value for this record based on the date?

Comment: Edit the question add sample output too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
SELECT p.[RecordID], p.[Date], p.[EmpID], p.[Reference], p.[TaskID], s.[Score]
FROM ProductionTable as p OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP (1) s.[Score]
      FROM StandingDataTable AS s
      WHERE s.[TaskID] = p.[TaskID] AND
            s.[DateActiveFrom] <= p.[Date]
      ORDER BY S.DateActiveFrom DESC
    ) s;
```

You might want score basis on Record Level if so, change the `where` clause in `apply`.

Comment: Brilliant, I wasn't sure if `OUTER APPLY` would work here, but that's done the trick. Just as an FYI, I had to add `desc` to the `ORDER BY`. Thanks again.